# Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.String'. c#

Tags: c#, mysql, livecharts

I'm trying to display the dates and restored it to the `Labels = strings`,
but I got an error on line `list.Add((string)myReader["Date"]);`

Here's my code:

```
con.Open();
myReader = cmdDB.ExecuteReader();
List<string> list = new List<string>();
while (myReader.Read())
{
    list.Add((string)myReader["Date"]);
}

string[] strings = list.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
cartesianChart1.AxisX.Add(new Axis
{
    Title = "Date",
    Labels = strings
});

cartesianChart1.AxisY.Add(new Axis
{
    Title = "Sales",
    LabelFormatter = value => value.ToString()
});
```

Any solution? Thank you! P.S. I'm using LiveCharts and MySQL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try like this

```
list.Add(myReader["Date"].ToString());
```

If you want you can also apply formatting to your date in the [ToString(dd-MM-yyyy) using Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
list.Add(Convert.ToString(myReader["Date"]));
```

It seems your `Date`column is not string but a datetime column.

Doing `(string)myReader["Date"]` tries explicit typecasting on a datetime column to string which is not possible. But `Convert.ToString` gives the string representation of your value.

Even if the value is `null`, `Convert.ToString(object value)` will return `null` instead of throwing exception like `.ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: if we have column of type DateTime in DataBase and String in asp.net core/Csharp application

**we can convert DateTime to string at store procedure level as**

e.g

```
    date_format(ReferralDate, '%d/%m/%Y') as ReferralDate,
```

Full example of Store procedure

```
SELECT  referralCostsID,
        ClientID,
        ReferralSource,
        date_format(ReferralDate, '%d/%m/%Y') as ReferralDate,
        AdCost,
        Notes

FROM referralcostssetup
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
 if (Convert.IsDBNull(columnValue))
 {
      return null;
 }
  return columnValue;
```

Ever validate is data is null or emty and return a value